# Change a raster from longitude display (-180, 180) to (0, 360)

Tags: raster, r, convert, display

Using R software, I want to modify the attached raster in order to visualize it centered on the Pacific Ocean. Indeed, I need to show the entire Oceania: in my opinion I have to shift from (-180,180) to (0,360)...

Coud you provide me the appropriate code?

[image: Plot to modify]

Comment: How did you generate the image in you question? Could you post the R code?

Comment: The raster was not produced by me, but downloaded from a website holding some raster shapefiles. The image I posted simply derives from the plot() function. If helpful, I can post the summay information of this raster.

Comment: You need a raster centered on the Pacific Ocean. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `terra::rotate` with argument `left=FALSE` for this

```
library(terra)
r <- init(rast(), "col")
x <- rotate(r, left=FALSE) 
plot(x)
```

Comment: Excellent! It works perfectly. I'm impressed by your solution: rapid, simple and extremely efficient. Thank you

Comment: Is this still the preferred solution to this question given that now we have terra?

Comment: updated the answer for terra

Answer (score 1):

Download this png image ([world_c.png](https://joseguerreroa.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/world_c.png)); that is a Cylindrical Equidistant Projection of world (2048×1024) centered on the Pacific Ocean.

[image]

With **gdal_translate** assign desired projection (latitude: -90, 90; longitude: 0, 360):

```
gdal_translate -a_srs WGS84 -a_ullr 0 90 360 -90 world_c.png geoworld_c.tif
```

Afterward in R:

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
> geoworld <- raster("geoworld_c.tif")
> plot(geoworld)
```

and you have raster displayed as centered on the Pacific Ocean.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you for your clear answer. I'll try it (I'm not familiar with rgdal, I have to learn it) and I'll inform you very soon about the outcome. But, is not possible to apply a method for my native raster? Many thanks

Comment: I tried. Unfortunately, I want to show a focus on Oceania continent and the raster has not sufficient resolution form my aims. I would like to convert rasters available at: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data/50m-natural-earth-2/