# Crop (bounding) box across 180° meridian

Tags: raster, r, latitude-longitude, clip

Having a problem in R's raster package -

I can't crop a raster across the 180° meridian - I'm trying to create a bounding box with longitude 120°-230° East

Simple enough, but the following code:

```
cropbox2 <-c(120,230,70,90)
crop2 <- crop(rt, cropbox2)
```

Doesn't return anything beyond 180E - it can't seem to cross the 180° meridian

Using minus

```
cropbox2 <-c(120,-130,70,90)
```

returns

```
Error in validityMethod(object) : invalid extent: xmin >= xmax
```

Surely this is a common problem people have run into?  I'm only trying to crop the N Pacific!

Answer (score 1):

Try @RobertHijmans' split-and-merge approach described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266535/change-a-raster-from-longitude-display-180-180-to-0-360/266539#266539), which is based on (i) splitting global data along the prime meridian, (ii) changing the extent of the Western hemisphere, and (iii) merging the two images back into one. The following code uses 700 mb geopotential height data of the northern hemisphere for replication purposes (see also `?vdendool` in **remote**). However, modifying it according to your needs should be rather straightforward:

```
## sample data
library(remote)
data(vdendool)

## see above for details
x1 <- crop(vdendool, extent(-180, 0, 20, 90)) # for global grid: -180, 0, -90, 90
x2 <- crop(vdendool, extent(0, 180, 20, 90))  # for global grid: 0, 180, -90, 90
extent(x1) <- c(180, 360, 20, 90)
m <- merge(x1, x2)

cropbox2 <-c(120, 230, 70, 90)
crop2 <- crop(m, cropbox2)

## verify extent
extent(crop2)
# class       : Extent 
# xmin        : 120 
# xmax        : 230 
# ymin        : 70 
# ymax        : 90

## display layers 1 to 4
spplot(crop2[[1:4]], scales = list(draw = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the answer -  I've tried that but get `Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,  : 
  different origin`
Because the origins (and extents) are marginally different - floating point error.
Adjusting the `tolerance = ` argument doesn't help either - I have to adjust it to 0.5 for it to run, and it puts a gap line one pixel thick between the two rasters

Comment: Hm, I see. Would it be possible to provide a sample of your data?

Comment: It's actually just standard ECMWF .75 x .75 NetCDF data - 850hPa temperature.  I'm not sure how to send it?  I'm thinking of getting a different scale - i.e. .5x.5 or 1x1 to see if the floating point (and therefore origin) problem goes away, what do you think?